# I want to create select tag in JavaScript and I want to add record into it from my database

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Following code creates select tag. I am creating option here. and assigning value to it. Actually I want to add my all "grad_id" into select dropdown list from database.but in JavaScript.

```
var gradeSelect=document.createElement('Select');
gradeSelect.id="grade[]";
gradeSelect.name="grade[]";

var opt1=document.createElement('option');
opt1.value="obj";
opt1.textContent="obj";

gradeSelect.appendChild(opt1);
```

On the place of " obj " I want to add id's from database.

Comment: The proper way would be getting the list of IDs from DB with an AJAX (`xmlHttpRequest`) bringing up the data or you could print the list somewhere server-side and then getting it. By printing I mean making the query and write a json into a js var, for example: <script>var dbIds = { <? echo $queryFormatedAsJsonBefore; ?> } </script>

Comment: I am able to get list of id's but i don't no how to assign it to option .Will you please give me any example ,it will really help full for me.

Comment: SoonDead's answer explain what I said clearly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that javascript executes in the client's browser, so it's not possible to directly access the database from there (I'm assuming you are talking about a traditional database on the server not WebSQL, LocalDB or something similar.

What javascript *can* access for example, is the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM). For example you can create elements and insert it into the DOM (like you do it in your example), but you can also access the elements that are already there.

You can also create [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) requests. It's an asynchronous request to the server that you can use to get the data you want.

However you choose to access your database you will not manage without some serverside code. Seeing your question, it is not clear what technologies you use to generate your html (PHP. ASP, JSP, Ruby, etc...). But whatever you use the pattern remains the usual:

1. **Create a page** you get the data from. That page should be **XML** or **[JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON)** (or HTML in very basic cases) and only contain the data you want to get from the server.
2. On the client side (javascript) **create an AJAX request** to the page you created in the previous step. This way you are able to get your desired data to javascript, where you can do anything you want with it.
3. Finally transform and use the data.

Let's say you were able to do the first two steps, and you have your data in (for example) [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON). And you have a variable containing the JSON in string. Like this:

```
var response = '[ { "id": 1, "text": "First" }, { "id": 2, "text": "Second" } ]';
```

You didn't need to type it like this, you got it from the server.

What to do with this? [Make a javascript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) from it:

```
var responseObj = JSON.parse(response);
```

This will return an object that is an array of 2 objects containing an id and text property.

Then go through it with a loop:

```
var gradeSelect=document.createElement('Select');
gradeSelect.id="grade[]";
gradeSelect.name="grade[]";

for (var i = 0; i < responseObj.length; i++) {
    var current = responseObj[i];
    var opt=document.createElement('option');

    opt.value = current.id;
    opt.textContent = current.text;

    gradeSelect.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Feel free to browse around in the [MDN portal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), you can learn a lot from it.

Is this what you were looking for?

---

**EDIT**:

Looking at your example you only want ID's from the server:

```
var response = '[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 20, 1000 ]';
var responseObj = JSON.parse(response); // Will return a list of numbers
```

And then:

```
var gradeSelect=document.createElement('Select');
gradeSelect.id="grade[]";
gradeSelect.name="grade[]";

for (var i = 0; i < responseObj.length; i++) {
    var current = responseObj[i];
    var opt=document.createElement('option');

    opt.value = current;
    opt.textContent = current

    gradeSelect.appendChild(opt);
}
```

---

**EDIT2**:

An other method is to render the values into the original response. This way there is no need for an additional ajax request.

If I understand your comment correctly, you are doing something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div id="hidden_container">
        <input type="hidden" class="grade_id" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" class="grade_id" value="2" />
        <input type="hidden" class="grade_id" value="3" />
        <input type="hidden" class="grade_id" value="4" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I have wrapped the hidden fields with a container div that has an ID. This will help me select the contents.

Now you need to parse those inputs and convert them to an array of numbers.

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('hidden_container').getElementsByTagName('input');
var numbers = [];    

for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    numbers.push(inputs[i].value);
}
```

The `numbers` variable is an array of numbers. If you check my code above you can use this variable in place of `responseObj`, and you are done.

The question with this method is that why you didn't render the options by php in the first place. If you can render the hidden fields, you may also be able to render the select options.

Comment: Thanks now i got it. I am using php and javascript .and my backend is mysql.

Comment: Hey I am fetching my grade_id into hideen field in php  and tring to pass that array from php to javascript.  I tried it using getElementBy Id, but I am unable to fetch array using getElementBy().value

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example. I think it will help you out!

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp